# $A y= b$ in $C(X)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff topological space, and $C(X)$ denote the ring of all complex valued continuous functions on $X$. If $A\in C(X)^{m\times n}$, $b\in C(X)^{m\times 1}$, and for all $x\in X$, $b(x)$ belongs to the range of $A(x)$, then does there exist a $y\in C(X)^{n \times 1}$ such that $Ay =b$?

Comment: Hint: look at the case $m = n = 1$ first.

Comment: I see. For example if $X=[0,1]$, $b(x)=\sqrt{x}$, $A(x)=x$, then there is no solution. Thanks!

Comment: @user186962: I suggest you write and accept your own solution.

Comment: That was fast. I'm impressed. (And second Martin's suggestion.)

Answer (score 3):

If $X=[0,1]$, $b(x)=\sqrt{x}$, $A(x)=x$, then there is no solution.

(Thanks again Daniel Fischer!)